# WooCommerce Subscription - PayPal Reference Transactions

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, transactions

I am using **woo commerce** subscription plugin and integrate pay-pal as a payment method. We are selling one subscription which is monthly based.

My issue is that, in Subscription Product, we received payment through pay-pal but Subscription from woo commerce did not activate.

After doing some research I integrate API Credentials, but now I am getting error about reference transaction.

I am getting below error.

> PayPal Reference Transactions are not enabled on your account, some subscription management features are not enabled. Please contact
>   PayPal and request they enable PayPal Reference Transactions on your
>   account.

Now I am getting confused that how to set billing agreement, how to set pre-approval payment. where we need to set on pay-pay or on our website. When we called to pay-pay they are saying that Reference Transaction is active on your account.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this is for PayPal Express Checkout; by default Reference Transactions is "not" enabled on any account. However it can be added by request if you call the business support line to get it added.

The steps are described by [WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/faq/paypal-reference-transactions/) on how to get this feature added.

Hope this helps 8^)